# Almost every internet application times out after 5 minutes for about 2-3 seconds

Tags: internet, gaming, timeout

I am having a lot of troubles with almost every internet application I use (mostly online gaming) but whenever I timeout, I completely lose connection to everything on my computer for about 1-2 seconds (4-5 seconds because of latency on game servers).

No one else on other computers are having this issue, which is why I am confused. I asked around on a game I play (because I thought that game was the issue at first) and they told me I needed to buy a 30$ product in order to play correctly. Which is insane to me and does not allow me to do much of anything online without losing what I am doing.

If they are any tests that you need me to run I will gladly run them, as I am out of ideas, So if anyone could help me, it would be very appreciated.

Edit:
I ran another test and it is showing a lot of drops, but when I test the individual hope i don't see the disconnects. 
https://pastebin.com/HnV8jPUw

Edit2: I ran both tracerts and they both time out on the 7th and 8th hop.

Comment: Please format your question. And FYI, i should be I! Use paragraphs. Questions whcih are easy to read usually get better responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A. Initial test:

A1. Use `tracert` to your game server to obtain list of hops from your computer to game server.

A2. Based on the list, constant ping the nearest computer to see whether the connection has intermittent outages and evaluate the result.

A3. If there were no outages, repeat step A2 with next server (one hop further).

A4. If there were these outages you described in the question, then focus to Athat connection between last server without problems and this server. Based on their role, you can understand what to diagnose (or to whom report your problems).

#### B. Follow up:

B1. Try from another computer using the same connection (e.g. in your home). This will show whether the problem is directly in your computer or if it is in your home connection.

B2. If the problem appears to be in your home connection, try connecting without your router.

B3. Test your computer with different internet providers (e.g. use mobile connection or take the computer to friend's home who has different internet provider). **Write down the `tracert` output made there so you can compare it to `tracert` output you obtained in step A1.** This will show you whether the problem is at your home internet provider or not.

**Edit:**

As you found outages in A-steps at 4th hop, please check with owner of 3rd server why there is problem pinging 4th server and give them your findings. (Including evidence that 3rd server has no outages, but 4th server has them.) If you don't know who is the owner of 3rd server, you can check using online Whois services (there are more of them). I think it is quite likely your internet provider. Then raise a technical support request with them.

Of course, if there is minimum of `ping` outages between 3rd and 4th hop, but there is much more for example between 5th and 6th hop, then the main problem you want to address is there. The investigation based on these statistics is on you. Now you should understand the approach so you can determine the weakest point by yourself and contact the support about it.

If you compare `tracert` output made when using your mobile connection with `tracert` made at A1, you should be able to identify common servers at the bottom of the list which never fail. Because you have no failures over mobile connection.

Edit 2:

Bing pinged without problem but Google has problems? Check the `tracert`. Are there any servers in the route which are present when you are pinging Google, but which are not in the route when you are pinging Bing? This is unlikely, but if you can find the evidence, submit it to your ISP. You need to rule out going hop-by-hop which servers on the route work rock-solid and which have issues. Then follow up addressing that part of the infrastructure. Double check there are no other factors involved like weather, which can do outages on radio networks.

Comment: I ran the tracert and pinged all the servers that popped up, but none seemed to show any problems. A few of the servers in the tracert timed out, so i have no idea what to do there. https://pastebin.com/QmFgnDuh

Comment: There are only a few timeouts, and they start at the 4th hop. and its about 1 every 5-10 minutes. Also i just tested through a mobile connection and there are no problems, when i test through my router it has a problem.

Comment: @EnchantedDirt – from my viewpoint, the answer is now complete. If it was helpful, you can mark it as accepted. If it has good quality, you can also upvote it.

Comment: There are still a lot of drops in the tests, i asked my ISP and they said there was no problem that they could see, so they just restarted the radio. The problem i have is with every game i play, not just the server i tested. I'm just as a loss, because i have no idea what to do.

Comment: @EnchantedDirt – I see. Is there something what I can do about that? Some missing part of the answer etc. Of course, you can always go through steps B1-B3. If you find this way that the problem is in your ISP and they are unable to do anything about that, you can think about mobile connection or changing your ISP.